# CSS media queries Fluid images

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm in the process of creating Fluid images for my website (see the CSS below)
I'm taking a mobile first approach when it comes to media queries.

My question is - what exactly does  **'image-rendering: auto';**  do?

Does this rule ensure optimal image quality at any size? Should I be using this rule when apply mobile styles?

Should I be using  **image-rendering: OptimizeQaulity;** ?

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    image-rendering: auto;
}
```

Many thanks,
P

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Answer (score 0):

Image Rendering describes the process of how the browser does work with your (on mobile versions probably) overcalled images when downscaling them.

`image-rendering: optimizeQuality` trys to give you the best looking result possible. But on mobile first you may want to try `image-rendering: optimizeSpeed`.

For further information you can google `image rendering css` which will result in a lot of information. My quick tipps is the [htmlcss.wikia right here](http://htmlcss.wikia.com/wiki/Image-rendering) or the [mozilla docs article](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering).

If you need further information feel free to ask.

Best regards,
Marian.